# Why can't the map be initialized?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, initializer-list, move-constructor, deleted-functions

Given the following code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>

struct sstruct {
    std::string content;
    std::string_view name;
    std::mutex mtx;

    sstruct(std::string content_, std::string_view name_)
            : content(std::move(content_)), name(name_) {
    }

    std::string get_content() {
        return "";
    }
};

int main() {

    std::unordered_map<std::string, sstruct> map{
            {
                    "pippo", {"dddd", ""}
            }
    };

    std::cout << map["pippo"].content << std::endl;
}
```

This doesn't compile with the following error:

```
C:\Users\alt\Desktop\main.cpp(23): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::unordered_map<std::string,sstruct,std::hash<std::string>,std::equal_to<std::string>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string,sstruct>>>'
C:\Users\alt\Desktop\main.cpp(27): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

I would like to avoid initializing the mutex in the constructor.

https://godbolt.org/z/eqKG6jac1

Comment: You probably need to at least make `sstruct` movable. `map["pippo"]` also requires `sstruct` to be default constructible

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the class `std::mutex` is neither copyable nor moveable.

Consider redesigning of your class like

```
struct sstruct {
    std::string content;
    std::string_view name;
    static std::mutex mtx;

    sstruct(std::string content_, std::string_view name_)
            : content(std::move(content_)), name(name_) {
    }

    std::string get_content() {
        return "";
    }
};
```

Otherwise try something like the following

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, sstruct> map;

auto [it, success] = map.try_emplace( "pippo", "dddd", "" );

if ( success )
{ 
    std::cout << it->second.content << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
auto it2 = map.find( "pippo" );

if (it2 != map.end())
{
    std::cout << it2->second.content << '\n';
}
```

or

```
auto &obj = map.at( "pippo" );
std::cout << obj.content << '\n';
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible that way.. I needed to have a different mutex on each entry of the map

Comment: @AlbertoTiraboschi Then you should make a move constructor that handles the mutex member.

Answer (score 0):

`unordered_map::operator[]`  There are two cases, the key exists time and the return value; when the key does not exist, a empty value will be inserted, and the type of the value requires a no-argument constructor

Comment: Srroy!!! The original answer was wrong. I have moditied the original answer